# Simulate Touchscreen Input On Android

Tags: android, touchscreen

I have had a very unfortunate accident with my Samsung Galaxy S2 and the screen has suffered a complete shatter (top to bottom! - was closed in a car door)

I have downloaded and am running Droid@Screen to make sure the phone itself isn't damaged and can see that the screen is sat on the pattern lock screen. Is there a way I can simulate a touchscreen input from the PC?

I just need to unlock the screen then can use Kies Air to remove all of my pics and videos and important files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I can simulate a touchscreen input from the PC?

You can attempt to [use `monkeyrunner`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html), though I have no idea if that can automate the lockscreen.

Comment: hmm, a little too advanced for me. I was hoping there is something out there that allows me to simply click on the screen on the pc and draw in the pattern. Once it's unlocked theres no issue. Such a pain!

Comment: @LiamBee: Please bear in mind that StackOverflow is for programming questions. For that purpose, `monkeyrunner` is a reasonable tool. If you are not interested in solutions for programmers, you should be asking your question somewhere else, such as http://android.stackexchange.com.